# FileFilter for JFileChooser doesn't filter files - don't why, have code

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, filefilter

I want to choose only .csv files with FileChooser but when chooser opens I see all extensions. Do I need to set somehing more then this?

```
        btnFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                        chooser = new JFileChooser(); 
                        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
                        chooser.setDialogTitle("Choose Value File");
                        chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new CSVFilter());

                        if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { 
                          System.out.println("getCurrentDirectory(): " 
                             +  chooser.getCurrentDirectory());
                          System.out.println("getSelectedFile() : " 
                             +  chooser.getSelectedFile());
                          }
                        else {
                          System.out.println("No Selection ");
                          }

            }
        });
```

and Filter is nested class

```
class CSVFilter extends javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter {
      public boolean accept(File f) {

        return f.isFile() || f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".csv");
      }

      public String getDescription() {
        return "*.csv";
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your condition `return f.isFile() || f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".csv"); ` will return true for all the files since `f.isFile()` for files will return true. You need to use `&&` instead of `||` as stated by @User1.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe it should be:

```
    return f.isFile() && f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".csv");
```

not:

```
    return f.isFile() || f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".csv");
```

Comment: +1: Had same thing in mind as soon as I went through the code.

Answer (score 2):

The logic is wrong. It should be

```
return f.isFile() && f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".csv");
```

Currently you are accepting any file.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `FileFilter` for filtering out files from view. `ChoosableFileFilter` do not hide files from view, just avoid selecting them. Take a look at [JFileChooser#setFileFilter(javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setFileFilter%28javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter%29)

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
@Override
public boolean accept(File f) {
    return (f.isFile() && f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".csv")) || f.isDirectory();
}
```

It respects directories too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem would likely be with this line:

```
return f.isFile() || f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".csv");
```

That will return true if the File `f` is a file, regardless of whether or not it is a .csv file.

You probably want an AND (&&) condition rather than an OR (||) condition. You want to accept any File where it is a file AND it's extension is .csv.

Answer (score 1):

try to do like this:

```
 public boolean accept(File file) {

        return file.isDirectory() || file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".csv");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you CSVFilter you have method called accept, which returns `TRUE` if the input parameter is `file OR csv file`.

It will always return `TRUE` with a valid file parameter.

The condition shoud be

```
...
if (f.isFile() && f.isCSVFile())
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually set the filefilter not just add it as optional filter

```
chooser.setFileFilter(new CSVFilter());
```